# On downloading Ubuntu Desktop, the .iso files gets converted to a zip file

Tags: system-installation, iso

I tried downloading ubuntu desktop for setting it up as a VM on my windows 10 machine. After it downloads, the ISO disk image gets converted to a zip. Extracting the zip for installation doesn't help either. Anything else I could try??

Comment: Do you have WinRAR installed in Windows 10? If so, WinRAR associated the file type to be opened with its zip unzip utility. Try installing 7-Zip instead.

Comment: The iso file probably didn't spontaneously convert to zip. Windows just associated the file type to be opened with the zip unzip utility. Right click on the file and choose "open with another application" or something similar.

Comment: So, uninstalling WinRAR and installing 7-zip does the trick?

Comment: what "other application" do i open it with?

Comment: Go to the Ubuntu.,com and look for how to create the installation USB using Windows. There you will find the link to download the application you need.

Comment: For installing Ubuntu in a VM, you just need the VM software. Open that software and follow instructions to create a new VM. At some point you will be asked to choose an iso file from inside the VM software. Select the folder where the iso file is, and you should be able to select it.

Comment: You don't need to install or uninstall anything (for this). Just use the .iso as an image, be it for writing a DVD or USB, or selecting it as the virtual optical disk when installing it in VirtualBox or VMware. Don't open the .iso, *use* the .iso. It matters not one iota what it opens with if you don't open it - and you don't need to do anything of the sort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Ubuntu iso file did not get converted to a zip file. WinRAR associated the iso file type to be opened with its zip unzip utility. To prevent this from happening install 7-Zip free, open-source file archiver in Windows 10 instead of WinRAR.

Comment: 7Zip, (P7zip), is the first app I install with any new OS. +10. Makes secure encrypted archives also.

Comment: thanks, i downloaded 7zip and the issue got resolved